# Conditionally allow supply of allocators to wrapped objects

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, allocator

I'm creating a container that can be templated on the string type it uses for its members, either it's an owning or non-owning string (`std::string` vs `std::string_view`). For the case of the non-owning string, I can't supply an allocator and hence I have to convince the compiler to write a constructor that doesn't take an alloctor. Here's my current approach but I have yet multiple problems to solve:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:27,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:27,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:27,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:27,startLineNumber:18),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aconcept+uses_allocator_general+%3D+requires+%7B%0A++++typename+T::allocator_type%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+StringType+%3D+std::string%3E%0Astruct+URL+%7B%0A++++using+allocator_type+%3D+std::conditional_t%3Cuses_allocator_general%3CStringType%3E,%0A++++++++typename+StringType::allocator_type,+void%3E%3B%0A%0A++++URL(allocator_type+allocator+%3D+%7B%7D)%0A++++++++:+mystr%7Ballocator%7D%0A++++%7B+%7D%0A%0A++++StringType+mystr%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++URL+myurl%3B%0A%0A++++URL%3Cstd::string_view%3E+myurl_view%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.62433862433862,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Os%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:54.49790794979079,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:45.50209205020921,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:61.37566137566137,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
concept uses_allocator_general = requires {
    typename T::allocator_type;
};


template <typename StringType = std::string>
struct URL {
    using allocator_type = std::conditional_t<uses_allocator_general<StringType>,
        typename StringType::allocator_type, void>;

    URL(allocator_type allocator = {})
        : mystr{allocator}
    { }

    StringType mystr;
};

int main() {
    URL myurl;

    URL<std::string_view> myurl_view;
}
```

1. This doesn't compile as `StringType::allocator_type` is evaluated before `std::conditional_t`. I would have to use some kind of indirection or SFINAE to retrieve the typedef conditionally.
2. Even if it were to compile, can I just conditionally void-erase the parameter even if it takes a default parameter? I don't think this is possible. What alternatives do I have?
3. Maybe there exists a more elegant solution for this problem that I don't know of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide two constraint constructors for the two cases respectively

```
template <typename T>
concept uses_allocator_general = requires {
    typename T::allocator_type;
};

template <typename StringType = std::string>
struct URL {
    template<uses_allocator_general AllocStringType = StringType>
    URL(AllocStringType::allocator_type allocator = {})
        : mystr{allocator}
    { }

    URL() requires (!uses_allocator_general<StringType>) = default;

    StringType mystr;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/93beK37fv)

Comment: As elegant as it gets I suppose, thx!